# Kramers-Kronig for functions $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb C^3$?

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have a function $$\vec{\pi}_{B}: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb C^3$$ that depends parametrically on a value $B\in\Bbb R^+$. I have full knowledge of its imaginary part $$ \Im\{ \vec{\pi}_{B}\} = f(B)$$

Is there in general (or also under specific conditions) a way to use the [Kramers-Kroning relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations)
to "reconstruct" or calculate

$$\Re\{ \vec{\pi}_{B}\} \in \Bbb R^3$$

The problem emerges from some quantum mechanical considerations on the "mechanical momentum density" in a magnetic field.

My idea is to break it up componentwise somehow in something like $3\times3$ problems.

In case this is not possible, for a specific subproblem it would be already of interest to say something on the modulus $|\Re\{ \vec{\pi}_{B}\}|$ since I am specifically interested in points $\vec{r}_0$ where 
$$\vec{\pi}_{B=0}(\vec{r}_0)=\vec{0}$$ and on their dependency on $B$, while I know 
 $$ \Im\{ \vec{\pi}_{B}(\vec{r}_0)\} = f(B); \forall  B.$$

Most specifically the question then is if $|\Re\{ \vec{\pi}_{B}\}|$ remains $=0$ when "turning on the perturbation $B$".

Comment: The analytic extension isn't unique, you need to know  your harmonic function on an open subset of $\Bbb{C}^3$ not only on $\Bbb{R}^3$. If you really know it only on  $\Bbb{R}^3$ then you can put the imaginary part as $0$ there is an analytic function extending it.

Comment: @reuns What I understand is that $B$ will get the imaginary component of the domain then I know full $\vec{\pi}$ for $B=0$ in the co-domain, its $\Im$ I know anyway everywhere and the $\Re\vec{\pi} = 0$ there. (I actually know also full $\Re$, but my hopes would be that one express $\Re$ in terms of $\Im$).

Comment: @reuns: So, also does it mean that K-K is not suitable to determine the linear response?